# PowerShell variable within variable

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to add a variable `$numberOfNics` which adds nics based on the number.  Right now this is my code, and I am a little confused as to how to put it into a loop.  I know an array is probably the way to go but not quite sure how to make an array in this sense that just calls variables instead of sets them.

### old code:

```
$numberOfNics=1

$networkname1 = "ondemandport1"
$networkname2 = "ondemandport2"
$networkname3 = "ondemandport3"
$networkname4 = "ondemandport4"
$networkname5 = "ondemandport5"
$networkname6 = "ondemandport6"
$networkname7 = "ondemandport7"
$networkname8 = "ondemandport8"
$networkname9 = "ondemandport9"

$networkInterface1 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $networkname1

$networkInterface2 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $networkname2 

$networkInterface3 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $networkname3 

$networkInterface4 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $networkname4 

$networkInterface5 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $networkname5
```

To tidy this up, I would like to make a loop something like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numberOfNics; $i++)
{
    $networkInterface$i = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $networkname$i
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks Martin, but now I am having trouble calling the variable.

```
$networkInterfaces = 1 .. $numberOfNics | ForEach-Object { 
if ($a -eq 0){
    New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name "ondemandport$_" -Location $locationName -SubnetId $virtualNetwork.Subnets[$a].Id -PublicIpAddressId $publicIp.Id -force
    }
ElseIf ($a=1){
    New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name "ondemandport$_" -Location $locationName -SubnetId $virtualNetwork.Subnets[$a].Id -force
    }
Else{
    New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name "ondemandport$_" -Location $locationName -SubnetId $virtualNetwork.Subnets[2].Id -force 
    }

}
```

`#`also looking to make this into a array loop

```
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[1].Id -Primary
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[2].Id
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[3].Id
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[4].Id 
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[5].Id
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[6].Id
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[7].Id 
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[8].Id
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterfaces[9].Id
```

Error message: Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Id'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with one line:

```
$networkInterfaces = 1 .. $numberOfNics | ForEach-Object { New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name "ondemandport$_" }
```

Now you can access the interfaces by index, for example:

```
$networkInterfaces[2]
```

By the way, consider using ARM templates instead.

---

**Edit:**

```
$networkInterfaces = 1 .. $numberOfNics | ForEach-Object { 

    $isPrimary = $_ -eq 0 # set the first one as primary

    $nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name "ondemandport$_" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $nic.Id -Primary:$isPrimary
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, the one liner worked well, and I've added it to my code, however, now I am having errors when calling the variable.  I've edited my original post to show the error I am getting.

Comment: @doggydogworld The first interface would have index 0, maybe you get out of range here? However, you could try to use the `Get-AzureRemNetworkInterface` cmdlet to retrieve the nic, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$numberOfNics= 10
$networkname = "ondemandport"

$networkInterface = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -le $numberOfNics; $i++)
{
    $networkInterface += ,@( New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name ($networkname + $i ))
}
```

Not sure if it will work with the New-AzureRmNetworkInterface but works with other New- commands

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell `Get-Variable` cmdlet. One thing which I would like to point out is the `for loop` which you are using will not be limited till `$numberOfNics`, but as a matter of fact, it's length will depend upon `$networkname` variable. For example, you are having `networkname` variables from `$networkname1` to `$networkname9`, so your loop will look something like this -

```
$NetworkInfo = @()
for($i = 1; $i -le 9; $i++) {$NetworkInfo += Get-Variable("networkname" + $i)}
```

Now `$NetworkInfo` has

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
networkname1                   ondemandport1
networkname2                   ondemandport2
networkname3                   ondemandport3
networkname4                   ondemandport4
networkname5                   ondemandport5
networkname6                   ondemandport6
networkname7                   ondemandport7
networkname8                   ondemandport8
networkname9                   ondemandport9
```

You can put another `for` loop something like this -

```
$NetworkInterface = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NetworkInfo.Length; $i++)
{
    $NetworkInterface +=  New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NetworkInfo.Value[$i]
}
```

Individual elements can then be accessed by `$NetworkInterface[0], $NetworkInterface[1]`... and so on.